# What is the meaning of seeing Devi Durga in dream for non-Hindu?

Tags: durga, dream

I saw Devi Durga twice in dream this week. In the dream, I was offering pooja to the Devi, I am Muslim. what is the meaning of the dream according to Hinduism? what does seeing Hindu god in the dream signify?

Comment: Why is this off-topic? This should be re-opened

Comment: You should ask this question in Islam stack exchange TOO as you follow Islam @jafar

Comment: @Santanu I feel that Islam Stack Exchange members won’t be very appreciative of this.

Comment: @jafar I would suggest a couple of things.1)Pray to her for a sign in which you will believe without doubt,when you see it happen.2)I’d Preferably ask you to go and wait in a temple of another Durga/it’s premises,ideally when no one is around,as you may be able to focus on the Mother more easily,.3)When She does answer you,(this is a request from me),please ask her about me,and when will certain wishes I have be fulfilled(just mention me as Amethyst,Mother will know me and the wishes I’m talking about)

Answer (score 13):

Analysis of dreams(swapna) has been done in detail in the Agni Purana.I'll be quoting from the book [Essence of Dharma Sindhu](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/dharmasindhu/bookindex.php) that contains its summary.

> **Swapna Prakarana:** Swimming in a river or Sea, flying in the Sky, Graha-Nakshatra-Surya-Chandr a darshana, hiking a high building or a
>   temple, drinking hard drinks, eating meat, spraying krimi-ke etaas on
>   one’s body, viewing jewellery and golden articles, drowing in blood
>   streams, eating curd rice, wearing white clothes and applying
>   chandana and such other scented materials; **viewing Brahmanas ,
>   Devatas** and Kings, viewing women nicely decorated and dresses,
>   encountering a Vrishabha, milk, trees full of atrractive fruits;
>   scaling high mountains; obtaining mirrors, meat, flower garlands,
>   white flowers and meeting persons dressed in white **are all dreams of
>   auspiciousness.**

So, dream of Goddess Durga is certainly an auspicious one.What it indicates/signifies more specifically is given in the next passage.

> More results of Desirable Dreams are the views of Kings, elephan ts,
>   horses, Gold, Vrishabha, and scaling of trees would result in monetary
>   gains and Kutumba Vriddhi round the corner. .........**Dreams of cows,
>   horses, elephants or of Devata Murtis would usher in tidings of
>   propitiousness and Subha Karyas in the house**

And,since these analyses are same for everyone,being a hindu or not being one  won't matter here.

Answer (score 9):

It simply means that you were a devotee of Durgaji in some previous lifetime and she is reminding you to worship her again to complete your journey. You seem to be one lucky fellow because even those devotees don't see her in their dreams who have been worshipping her for a long time.
In fact a new study in psychology suggests that many of your dreams might be your memories from your past lives.