# Durga Devi dream - meaning for woman?

Tags: durga, devi, dream

I am a 22 year old Polish woman, non-hindu. Last night I had a dream about Durga Devi. The world was taken over by demons, it was all on fire, huge fire and flames everywhere. Me and some 2 other people that I've never seen before were asked by Devi if we allow her to fight. We agreed. Durga was tall as a building. She was riding a lion. She started to kill all the demons and put down the huge fire with a single small breath. 
What can it mean? I think this might mean that Durga will be there for me and help me fight even the biggest problem in my life. What you think?

Comment: Were you reading story of Mother Durga killing Mahisasura yesterday?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Was just about to ask this :-)

Comment: Not really, I know the story barely. I might just add that I studied Indian language and culture for a year on a university, it was 2 years ago ;) I did not think about anything Hindu-related lately. This dream was really a surprise, that's why I think it might be meaningful :)

Comment: Here is a related posted: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2553/what-is-the-meaning-of-seeing-devi-durga-in-dream-for-non-hindu

Comment: Is your house/locality has some paranormal issues/Bad Karmas and praying to some deity to help you. Usually Deities as well other entities can never enter your house and help/harm you unless you allow them thats they ask for permission. You heard the famous wordphrase "Let me in".

Answer (score 1):

Dreaming about devtas great people (saints munis) 
Your elderly dead, and god is considered very good 
Something very good is going to happen with you soon

Comment: One liner answers without any sources are not encouraged on this site. Please try to write a descriptive answer with citing some sources preferably from authentic Hindu scriptures. In its current state your answer is like a personal opinion and just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

It is very auspicious to have the dream of the goddess. Fire is also important part of your dream which is also connected with goddess Durga.

The fire of durgA will protect you from other negativities and difficulties in your life.

The name durgA itself means the one who is invincible and one who protects from difficulties. So I feel the meaning you have derived from your dream looks good. She is ready to protect her children.
You can also read more about Durga [here](https://vedanet.com/2016/10/09/the-meaning-of-durga/).

Let us see the Durga Suktam (Vedic hymn for goddess durgA)

> **जातवेदसे सुनवाम सोममरातीयतो निदहाति वेदः । स नः पर्षदति दुर्गाणि
>   विश्वा नावेव सिन्धुं दुरितात्यग्निः ॥१॥**
>
> Jaatavedase Sunavaama Somam-Araatiiyato Nidahaati Vedah | Sa Nah
>   Parssad-Ati Durgaanni Vishvaa Naave[a-I]va Sindhum Durita-Aty[i]-Agnih
>   ||1||
>
> Meaning: (We offer our oblations to the Fire of Durga to cross over
>   this very difficult ocean of worldly existence)
>
> 1.1: To that Jataveda (one from whom the Vedas are born) we press out the Soma (i.e. Invoke Her ardently); (We invoke that Jataveda) Who
>   consumes by Her Fire of Knowledge (Veda) all the Adversities (within
>   and without) (And frees us from the bondage of the world),
>   1.2: May that Agni (Fire of Durga) carry us over this Ocean of the World which is full of Great Difficulties and beset with great Perils;
>   like a Boat (carrying one over a very rough Sea),
>
> **तामग्निवर्णां तपसा ज्वलन्तीं वैरोचनीं कर्मफलेषु जुष्टाम् । दुर्गां
>   देवीँशरणमहं प्रपद्ये सुतरसि तरसे नमः ॥२॥**
>
> Taam-Agni-Varnnaam Tapasaa
>   Jvalantiim Vairocaniim Karma-Phalessu Jussttaam | Durgaam
>   Devii[ngu]m-Sharannam-Aham Prapadye Su-Tarasi Tarase Namah ||2||
>
> Meaning: (We offer our oblations to the Fire of Durga to cross over
>   this very difficult ocean of worldly existence)
>
> 2.1: To Her, Who is of the colour of Fire (Agni Varna) and blazing with Tapas (Tapasa Jwalantim); Who was born of that Fire (of Tapas)
>   (Vairochinim), and Who is worshipped through Fruits of Actions (Karma
>   Phalas) (offered to Her Fire as oblations),
>
> 2.2: To that Durga, to that Devi, I take Refuge (Sharanam Aham) by falling at Her Feet (Prapadye); (O Mother Durga, I Prostrate before
>   You) Please ferry me mercifully (over this Ocean of the World full of
>   great Difficulties and Perils),
>
> **अग्ने त्वं पारया नव्यो अस्मान् स्वस्तिभिरति दुर्गाणि विश्वा । पूश्च
>   पृथ्वी बहुला न उर्वी भवा तोकाय तनयाय शंयोः ॥३॥**
>
> Agne Tvam Paarayaa Navyo Asmaan Svastibhir-Ati Durgaanni Vishvaa |
>   Puush-Ca Prthvii Bahulaa Na Urvii Bhavaa Tokaaya Tanayaaya Shamyoh
>   ||3||
>
> Meaning: (We offer our oblations to the Fire of Durga to cross over
>   this very difficult ocean of worldly existence)
>
> 3.1: O Agni (Fire of Durga), You Who are eulogized (for carrying one across this Samsara); Please ferry us (too), by carrying us (i.e. our
>   Souls) over Your Auspicious Nature, and make us cross this World full
>   of Great Difficulties (Samsara), ...
>
> 3.2: ... (and also spread Your Auspicious Nature over the) Land and Earth, (so that the Earth) becomes abundantly Fertile and Green (and
>   we feel Your presence in external Nature); And fill us, (We who are)
>   Your Children with Your Bliss (so that we feel Your presence
>   internally),

Text to full hymn with translation [here](http://greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/devi_durga-durga_suktam.php). and audio [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WR_N0fGLrzo)

Comment: Format the answer properly. Poor formatted answer makes an answer less interesting. Fire in the above dream means difficulties.

Comment: @SreeCharan she will take care of all the difficulties/fire because of her direct association with fire. Durga's fire will take care of other fire.